# Let $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f: T \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function. Does $f$ have an antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, derivatives

The Fundamental Theorem of (differential and integral) Calculus states, that for any continuous function $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ the Riemann integral

$$F(\beta) = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(t) dt \quad \alpha, \beta \in (a,b)$$
is an antiderivative of $f$.

**My question is:** what happens when the domain of the continuous function $f$ is not an interval?

It is known that any open set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is the union of countable disjoint open interval. Using this fact, I think one can show, that any continuous function $f: O \to \mathbb{R}$ has an antiderivative. But what about a closed domain?

Comment: The opposite of “open” is. *not* “closed.” What do you do with $T=\{1/n: n\in\Bbb N\}$ or with the Cantor set?

Comment: In general, it does not make sense to talk about antiderivatives on non-open sets, since differentiability is only defined for functions on open domains. Of course you can also talk about one-sided derivatives, but you have to be careful then.

Comment: The concept of differentiation only works at all at accumulation points of the domain, and usually is restricted to interior points. So before you can call something an "anti-derivative" on a non-open domain, you have to define differentiation there.